# glMultMatrix/glLoadMatrix more efficient than glRotatef, or glTranslatef?

Tags: c++, opengl

Suppose I have the following code:

```
glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f -5.0f);
```

Is this less efficient than utilizing one's own custom matrix via the glLoadMatrix function that accomplishes the same functionality?

Also, I know that when multiplying matrices to form a custom linear transformation, the last matrix multiplied is the first transformation to take place. Likewise, is this the case if I utilize the above code? Will it translate, then rotate about the Z axis, followed by rotations about the y and x axes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general if you assemble your matrix on your own and load it via glLoadMatrix or glMultMatrix your program will run faster. Unless you make stupid mistakes in your own matrix routines that ruin the performance of course.

This is because the glRotate glTranslate etc. functions do quite a bit more than the pure math. They have to check the matrix-mode. glRotate has to deal with cases where the axis is not passed as a unit-vector etc.

But unless you do this 10thousands times per frame I wouldn't worry about the lost performance. It adds up, but it's not that much.

My personal way of dealing with openGL transformations is to build the matrices in my code and only upload them to OpenGL via glLoadMatrix. This allows me to do lots of shortcuts like reversing the order of multiplications (faster to calculate than the way OpenGL does it). Also it gives me instant access to the matrix which is required if you want to do boundary box checks before rendering.

Needless to say code written with such an approach is also easier to port onto a different graphics API (think OpenGL|ES2, DirectX, Game-Consoles...)

Answer (score 3):

According to the OpenGL specs the glRotate and glTranslate are using their parameters to produce a 4x4 matrix, then the current matrix is multiplied by the (glRotate or glTranslate) produced matrix with the product replacing the current matrix.

This roughly means that in your enlisted code you have 4 matrix multiplications! On top of that you have 4 API calls and a few other calculations that convert the angles of glRotate to a 4x4 matrix.

By using glLoadMatrix you will have to produce the transformation matrix yourself. Having the angles and the translation there are way more efficient ways to produce that transformation matrix and thus speedup the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this less efficient than utilizing one's own custom matrix via the glLoadMatrix function that accomplishes the same functionality?

Very likely. However if you're running into a situation where setting of the transformation matrices has become a bottleneck you're doing something fundamentally wrong. In a sanely written realtime graphics program calculation of the transformation matrices should make only a very small amount of the things processed in total.

A example for very bad programming was something like this (pseudocode):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
for q in quads:
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(q.x, q.y, q.z)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, q.texture)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for v in [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)]:
        glVertex2f(v[0], v[1]
    glEnd()
    glPopMatrix()
```

Code like this will perform very poorly. First you're spending an awful lot of time in calculating the new transformation matrix for each quad, then you restart a primitive batch for each quad, the texture switches kill the caches and last but not least its using immediate mode. Indeed the above code is the the worst of all OpenGL anti-patterns in one single example.

Your best bet for increasing rendering performance is to avoid any of the patterns you can see in above example.

Answer (score 1):

Those matrix functions are implemented in the driver, so they might be optimized. You will have to spend some time to write your own code and test if the performance is better or not than the original OpenGL code.

On the other hand in "new" version of OpenGL all of those functions are missing and marked as deprecated. So in new standard you are forced to use custom math functions (assuming that you are using Core profile)