# Quaternion object rotation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rotation

Since few days I'm trying to implement quaternion rotation for android OpenGL ES. I would like to get function with input `quaternion(x,y,z,w)`. This function will be set rotation for `GL10` object. GL10 object have only `gl.glRotatef(y, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` function providing setting position in Euler angles. I tried that class https://github.com/TraxNet/ShadingZen/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/traxnet/shadingzen/math/Quaternion.java to create Matrix but it still don't work. I would be grateful if someone could show/write  how to set position of GL10 object by putting as parameter `quaternion(GL10setRotation(Quaternion q)).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glRotatef` is just a multiplication of the current matrix with a rotation matrix (plus associated boundary checks).

One way to do this in OpenGL 1 (using the linked Quaternion class) is:

```
Matrix rotation = new Matrix();
quaternion.toMatrix(rotation);
glMultMatrixf(rotation.getAsArray(), 0);
```

Do note that `glRotate` and `glTranslate` are [slower than doing the Matrix math yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613469/glmultmatrix-glloadmatrix-more-efficient-than-glrotatef-or-gltranslatef) and using `glLoadMatrix`. In general, if performance is important, I'd advise against using OpenGL 1 entirely.

Comment: You are correct. Anyways, if using OpenGL's fixed api is a must, I would do all my rotations using quaternions and as the last step load the matrix as you mentioned with glLoadMatrix.